# How to install SSD on late 2007 MacBook Pro (15 inch)

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, memory

I have a slot on the left-hand side of my MacBook Pro (late 2007, NOT a unibody) and am wondering: is this slot suited for an SSD that I can simply stick in? Or would I have to install an SSD internally?

Answer (score 1):

Since Yosemite needs drivers for those and it has to be signed([here is discussion of possible problems with that kind of SSD on Apple discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5468599?tstart=0)) you much better off installing SSD inside the MBP in place of HDD.

[Here is instruction](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Core+2+Duo+Models+A1226+and+A1260+Hard+Drive+Replacement/670) from iFixit how to do it.